# Firebase ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

While implementing Firebase push notification.

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
```

Tried changing linker flags, deleting Derived Data, pod deintegrate

[image: Error Description]

Comment: you can try FCM latest implementation code which is available on Github.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49169330/symbols-not-found-for-architecture-arm64)